# Thread id ( pthread_self) and the thread id shown by ps command are different

Tags: linux, multithreading

I have linux single - multi thread user process.

I) The pthread_self gives the thread id of each thread in it.

II)in ps -T command shows the Thread id of the threads.

But these dont match.
Please anyone can elobarate the difference.

I have a thread that is hanging seen in ps command, but have to find which thread it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is stated in man page of pthread_self: _The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2)._

Comment: You can't even be sure that the thing returned by `pthread_self()` is even an integer or any basic C type: "POSIX.1 allows an implementation wide freedom in choosing the type used to represent a thread  ID;  for  example, representation  using  either  an  arithmetic  type  or  a  structure is permitted.". Therefore you aren't even really supposed to print out its value.

Comment: understood pthread_self and gettid are different. how to map the ids listed in ps output, with the threads of our process? is there a way?